Recursividad infinita en petición login del usuario para la generación del token en Spring Boot ApiRest
Ando con un problema hace unas semanas y es que ando haciendo un proyecto ApiRest en SpringBoot y trabajando con Spring Security y Tokens, al querer generar el token de seguridad para los usuarios de mi aplicación, se genera un ciclo infinito en mi aplicación cuando hago la solicitud desde Postman, ya probé varias cosas, pero no encuentro el problema en el código que lo pueda generar, ya que la misma configuración si me funciono en otras aplicaciones que hice.
Les comparto fotos del error y del código para que pueda visualizarse.
ERROR:
2024-05-10T17:22:23.057-03:00 ERROR 26100 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1694) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:500) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy174.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)

Código
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.tienda.ropa.tienda_ropa.entities.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamReadException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
 
import static com.example.tienda.ropa.tienda_ropa.security.filter.TokenJwtConfig.*;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws AuthenticationException {
            User user = null;
            String username = null;
            String password = null;

            try {
                user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
                username = user.getEmail();
                password = user.getPassword();
            } catch (StreamReadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DatabindException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
            
    }
     //Para implementar este método es necesario desde el github de jwt implementarlo en el pom
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, //Es un método que se ejecuta si todo sale bien
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
                
                org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)authResult.getPrincipal(); //usuario pero de springsecurity
                String username = user.getUsername();
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = authResult.getAuthorities(); //Asignamos los roles que 
                Claims claims = Jwts.claims().add("authorities", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(roles)).build(); //Construye el claims que es un tipo de información que queresmos agregar al token
                

                String token = Jwts.builder().subject(username).expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000))//El token expira en una hora
                .claims(claims)
                .issuedAt(new Date()) //Fecha en la que se crea
                .signWith(SECRET_KEY).compact();//Generando el Token
                response.addHeader(HEADER_AUTORIZATION, PREFIX_TOKEN + token); //Se pasa el token al usuario

                Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
                body.put("token", token);
                body.put("username",username);
                body.put("message", String.format("Hola %s has iniciado sesión con éxito!", username));

                response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
                response.setContentType("aplication/json");
                response.setStatus(200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, //Método por si falla la verificación
            AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
                Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
                body.put("message", "Error en la autenticación o password incorrectos");
                body.put("error", failed.getMessage());

                response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
                response.setStatus(401);
                response.setContentType("aplication/json");
 
    }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import static com.example.tienda.ropa.tienda_ropa.security.filter.TokenJwtConfig.*;

public class JwtValidationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter{ //Valida el token creado al usuario
     
    public JwtValidationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
                
            String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTORIZATION); //Primero recuperamos el header, del token del cliente o postman

            if(header == null || !header.startsWith(PREFIX_TOKEN)){
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return ;
            }

            String token = header.replace(PREFIX_TOKEN, ""); //Le quitamos el prefix tooken para dejarlo limpio

            try{
                Claims claims = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(SECRET_KEY).build().parseSignedClaims(token).getPayload();
                String username = claims.getSubject();
                Object authoritiesClaims = claims.get("authorities");

                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =Arrays.asList(new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class, SimpleGrantedAuthoritiesJsonCreator.class).readValue(authoritiesClaims.toString().getBytes(), SimpleGrantedAuthority[].class));
                
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null, authorities);//el password se valida solo cuando creamos el token
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken); //Se autentica
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }catch(JwtException e){
               Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
               body.put("error", e.getMessage());
               body.put("message", "El token JWT no es valido");

               response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
               response.setStatus(401);
               response.setContentType("aplication/json");

            }

    } 
}


import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception{
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

//Clase usuario que va a existir un admin y los usuarios que van a gestionar sus vehiculos
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "dni"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;
   
    @NotEmpty
    private String dni;
    
    @NotNull
    private Integer age;
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    @NotEmpty
    private String image;
   
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"users","handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "rolesxusers",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id_user", "id_rol"})}
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Tax> taxs;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String lastname, String dni, int age, String email, String password, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.image = image;
        this.enabled = true;
        this.roles = new HashSet<>();
        this.taxs = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }

    

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }


    
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Set<Tax> getTaxs() {
        return taxs;
    }

    public void setTaxs(Set<Tax> taxs) {
        this.taxs = taxs;
    }

    public void setTax(Tax tax){
        this.taxs.add(tax);
    }
    

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       
        return 1;
    }

  

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (dni == null) {
            if (other.dni != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dni.equals(other.dni))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", dni=" + dni + ", age=" + age
                + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", enabled=" + enabled
                +  "]";
    }


}



import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"roles","handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public Role() {

    }

    public Role(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Role other = (Role) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


     
}

Espero que me puedan ayudar o asesorar por donde puede estar el error.
